# Unable to start npm

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, monodevelop, mean-stack

I am working on nodejs project and unable to start nodejs.

There are 2 folder one is frontend and other backend.

we put all front end code in to front end.
we start `grunt start` command for front end working fine.

Bu `npm start` does not working.

```
kailas.kokate@kailaskokate-desktop:~/kol-backend$ npm start

> Stack@0.0.0 prestart /home/kailas.kokate/kol-backend
> npm install

Stack@0.0.0 /home/kailas.kokate/kol-backend
+-- aws-sdk@2.2.33 
`-- multer-storage-s3@1.1.1  extraneous


> Stack@0.0.0 start /home/kailas.kokate/kol-backend
> nodemon ./bin/www

1 Mar 11:04:54 - [nodemon] v1.3.7
1 Mar 11:04:54 - [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
1 Mar 11:04:54 - [nodemon] watching: *.*
1 Mar 11:04:54 - [nodemon] starting `node ./bin/www`
104.196.20.83:9200
events.js:410
EventEmitter.listenerCount = function(emitter, type) {
                                     ^

RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at Function.EventEmitter.listenerCount (events.js:410:38)
    at Log.listenerCount (/home/kailas.kokate/kol-backend/node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/log.js:68:25)
    at Function.EventEmitter.listenerCount (events.js:412:20)
    at Log.listenerCount (/home/kailas.kokate/kol-backend/node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/log.js:68:25)
    at Function.EventEmitter.listenerCount (events.js:412:20)
    at Log.listenerCount (/home/kailas.kokate/kol-backend/node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/log.js:68:25)
    at Function.EventEmitter.listenerCount (events.js:412:20)
    at Log.listenerCount (/home/kailas.kokate/kol-backend/node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/log.js:68:25)
    at Function.EventEmitter.listenerCount (events.js:412:20)
    at Log.listenerCount (/home/kailas.kokate/kol-backend/node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/log.js:68:25)
    at Function.EventEmitter.listenerCount (events.js:412:20)
    at Log.listenerCount (/home/kailas.kokate/kol-backend/node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/log.js:68:25)
    at Function.EventEmitter.listenerCount (events.js:412:20)
    at Log.listenerCount (/home/kailas.kokate/kol-backend/node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/log.js:68:25)
    at Function.EventEmitter.listenerCount (events.js:412:20)
    at Log.listenerCount (/home/kailas.kokate/kol-backend/node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/log.js:68:25)
    at Function.EventEmitter.listenerCount (events.js:412:20)
    at Log.listenerCount (/home/kailas.kokate/kol-backend/node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/log.js:68:25)
    at Function.EventEmitter.listenerCount (events.js:412:20)
    at Log.listenerCount (/home/kailas.kokate/kol-backend/node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/log.js:68:25)
    at Function.EventEmitter.listenerCount (events.js:412:20)
    at Log.listenerCount (/home/kailas.kokate/kol-backend/node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/log.js:68:25)
    at Function.EventEmitter.listenerCount (events.js:412:20)
    at Log.listenerCount (/home/kailas.kokate/kol-backend/node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/log.js:68:25)
    at Function.EventEmitter.listenerCount (events.js:412:20)
    at Log.listenerCount (/home/kailas.kokate/kol-backend/node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/log.js:68:25)
    at Function.EventEmitter.listenerCount (events.js:412:20)
    at Log.listenerCount (/home/kailas.kokate/kol-backend/node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/log.js:68:25)
1 Mar 11:04:55 - [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Comment: When you issue the command npm start from the root directory of your nodejs project, node will look for a scripts object in your package.json file. If found, it will look for a script with the key start and run the command specified as its value.

Comment: What does your `package.json` say, for `scripts`. Does it have any start scripts installed?

Comment: Could be related to https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-js/issues/265